# How do you add an element to an existing element in a SimpleXML object

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I have an XML document similar to the following:

```
<contents>
  <module id="0">
  <module id="1">
  ...
</contents>
```

I would like to search the document by 'id' and then add one or more children to the node the search returns. How would one do this with SimpleXML or a combination of SimpleXML / DOM?

Comment: The PHP manual is a good place to look http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php

Answer (score 0):

That's the way to search element based on id using xpath query in simple xml:

```
$nodes = $xml->xpath('//DocSum[Item[@id="0"]]');
$book = $nodes[0];
```

Add children is something like this:

```
$book->addChild('name', 'Mr. Parser');
$book->addChild('actor', 'John Doe');
```

Here is a [more precise tutorial](http://benramsey.com/blog/2006/05/add-children-with-simplexml/).

Answer (score -1):

You can use either PHP:DOm or PHP:SimpleXML .It depends on what you want to achive.

If you just want to add a new node use PHP:SimpleXML. quite easy to understand.But add new node at the end of existing child nodes.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php

if you want to add new node before any specific child node. You should use PHP:DOm.Will give you more freedom but have a bit of learning curve.

Say if you want to add node after a particular node use :
http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php

Say if you want to add node before a particular node use :
http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.insertbefore.php

Hope this help

~K